# Capture stereo image using IVMECH's IVPort v2

Tags: raspicam

I have the IVPORT v2 (a raspberry camera multiplexer) and want to capture a image pair (1 from each of the 2 cameras) as close together as possible. Which code should I be looking at from their github? I tried 3 functions from test_ivport_quad.py:

picam_capture()
images way too far apart sometimes 400ms seconds apart. I need like 30ms apart max.

still_capture()
even farther apart than picam_capture(), may improve if I get rid of preview?

picam_sequence()
can't get the camera to switch reliably in 2 images, often captures 2 images with same camera.

Can someone point me to where I can find code that will capture exactly 1 image from each camera as close together as possible?

github
https://github.com/ivmech/ivport-v2

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off asking this of the package maintainers? Or raising a support ticket with them.

Comment: Did both but doubt they'd answer so just wanna see if anyone used it here..